# Retrieve github releases with libcurl while being anonymous

Tags: c++, c, rest, github, libcurl

With [this minimal program](https://github.com/TheQuantumPhysicist/CurlWithSSLMinimal), I can download a text file and print it using libcurl. And I do this anonymously, just like any https get request.

Now this URL: https://api.github.com/repos/bitcoin/bitcoin

Is an example of a Restful API case I don't understand but interests me because I need to retrieve the releases of my project anonymously on Github. If you click on it, you get the JSON information anonymously on your web browser with no problems. It works without any authentication. But then when I put that URL in my minimal program, I get error 403!

So any normal https URL works fine in my minimal program, but this Github URL doesn't.

Why am I getting error 403? Do I have to authenticate in some way (and I don't mean with my personal username and password because my requirement is to get this anonymously)? Is this a bug in Github or my code?

Comment: Probably hitting [this](https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Why does it work in the web browser without anything? That's what puzzles me!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist because all web browsers have a non-empty User Agent, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I know now what my mistake is. I seem to have confused authentication username/password with the so called "user agent". Adding this line to libcurl configuration:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Dark Secret Ninja/1.0");
```

will make it work. No authentication is required.